# 'CompactToken parsing failed with error code: -2147184105' when trying to access Users with Office 365 Unified API using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, office365, office365api, office365-restapi, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to list users using Office 365 Unified API with the following code:

```
$TenantID = "xxx"
$F_ClientID = "yyy"
$F_ClientSecret = "zzz"

Add-Type @'
using System;
public class OAuthContext{
    public string AccessToken{get;set;}
    public string TokenType{get;set;}
    public string ExpiresIn{get;set;}
    public string RefreshToken{get;set;}
}
'@

$Uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($TenantID)/oauth2/token"
$ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
$Headers = @{}
$Body = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='+$F_ClientID+'&client_secret='+$F_Clie    ntSecret+'&resource"=https://graph.microsoft.com')
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $Uri -Headers $Headers -ContentType $ContentType -Body $Body
$Response

$Context = New-Object OAuthContext
$Context.AccessToken = $Response.access_token
$Context.ExpiresIn = $Response.expires_in
$Context.RefreshToken = $Response.refresh_token
$Context.TokenType = $Response.token_type
$Context

$Headers = @{}
$Headers.Add('Authorization',$Context.TokenType + ' ' + $Context.AccessToken)
$Headers

$Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"

Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $Uri -Headers $Headers
```

As seen from the result, the access token seems to be successfully generated.
But when trying to list the users, I get the following error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {
"error": {
"code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
"message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: -2147184105",
"innerError": {
  "request-id": "067c7044-0c59-4a39-86ac-b89e6b13229c",
  "date": "2016-02-12T17:09:56"
}
}
}
At line:41 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $Uri -Headers $Headers
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation:     (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I don't really know what I am doing wrong here!
Thanks for your help!

Comment: my token is begin with "EwAAA61DBAAUGCC...." and i understand the all jwt tokens should begin with "ey...." should i encode/decode my token with other parameters? my token was extracted from my iphone

Answer (score 6):

The response actually indicates that the access token was not successfully generated or passed to the graph endpoint. Microsoft Graph couldn't parse it as a JWT token and thus attempted to process it as a Microsoft Account/Live Id compact token, which also failed. Please check the response that you got from the call to login.microsoftonline.com and that the token passed to graph.microsoft.com is a valid JWT token.

Comment: I tried to verify the output here http://jwt.io/
!(http://r04i.imgup.net/JWT8280.png).
It seems like valid token, don't you think?

Comment: The correct audience for the graph.microsoft.com endpoint is 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000. For some reason you have 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000. Could you double check the following line in your code:
$Body = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='+$F_ClientID+'&client_secret='+$F_ClientSecret+'&resource"=https://graph.microsoft.com')

There seems to be an extra double quote character after resource.

Comment: @MarekRycharski I have the same issue but I don't see 0000002. Can you help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754060/microsoft-office-api-invalidauthenticationtoken-compacttoken-parsing-failed-with ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check through this page if the client secret that you are sending matches the result of the [page](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) when coding it?

The recipient when viewing 'application / x-www-form-urlencoded' will decode the url, and if your client secret is not encode well, someone characters will disappear. (This was my problem)

[I used this code and it worked](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-authentication/tree/master/Demos/01-rest-via-powershell#create-the-powershell-script)

Answer (score -1):

What i recommend is to test your query you are sending to the graph api by using the graph explorer tool first. and then mimic the same request in your PS script.

https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net

Comment: grahexploerer2 is not available anymore

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer