# InvalidAuthenticationToken - CompactToken parsing failed with error code: -2147184105

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using V1 in order to have a token from Microsoft REST API. (We have Office 365 tenant and I used to successfully get all resources without any problem but not anymore.

```http
clientId =8a67......de4b6
clientSecret =J58k8....5EU=
redirectUri =http://example.com...
resourceUrl =https://graph.microsoft.com
authority = https://login.microsoftonline.com/f02633....a603/oauth2/token
```

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/f0263...0be3/oauth2/authorize?client_id=8a6..b6&redirect_uri=http://example.com&response_type=code&scope=mail.read`

It gave me a token structured as [follows](https://w68i.imgup.net/ScreenShot29e8.png) on [JWT](https://jwt.io/). It says invalid signature but not sure what is wrong.

Once I have the token, I tried the following curl call

```
curl -i https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Authorization: Barer eyJ.[TOKEN]...UNa6nfw'
```

Instead of the messages, I received the following error:

```http
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8Cl23
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
request-id: af2390b1-a9b...5ab9
client-request-id: af2390,....a615ab9
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West US","Slice":"SliceA","ScaleUnit":"000","Host":"AGSFE_IN_4","ADSiteName":"WST"}}
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 19 Jan 2017 23:55:43 GMT
Content-Length: 268

{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: -2147184105",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "af2390b1-...5ab9",
      "date": "2017-01-19T23:55:44"
    }
  }
}
```

I looked at similar questions on SO but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, the **Barer** of `authorization` header is a typo. The correct parameter should be like `authorization: bearer {access_token}`.

Second, it seems that you were mixing using the Azure V1.0 endpoint and V2.0 endpoint. If you were developing with V1.0 endpoint which apps were resisted from Azure portals, when we acquire the access token we need to specify the **resource** parameter instead of **scope**.

The **scope** parameter is used for Azure V2.0 endpoint which apps are resisted from [here](http://apps.dev.microsoft.com).

And the authorization endpoint for Azure AD likes below:

V1.0:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize
```

V2.0:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
```

More detail about the code grant flow with Azure AD, you can refer links below:

[Authorize access to web applications using OAuth 2.0 and Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code)

[v2.0 Protocols - OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code)

Comment: If you stop by the Bay Area, I can buy you a coffee or grab a beer!! I guess I was exhausted not to see "Barer". lol

Comment: Xue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818683/how-can-i-filter-emails-from-a-specific-email-address-on-office-365-api .. Last question here. Almost done!! Thanks.

Comment: Xue, I am trying to migrate app to v2 and here is the problem I am facing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074320/office-365-v2-api-authorization-code-is-malformed-or-invalid. Thank you brother!