# How can I filter emails from a specific email address on Office 365 API?

Tags: azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I've users with thousands of emails but I need to fetch only unread emails from specific people. I have the following call but it is not working for me.

```
curl -i https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages$filter=From/EmailAddress/Address eq 'alerts-noreply@mail.windowsazure.com' H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Authorization: Bearer token ....'

{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery: users/020f1da4-031d-4....26513bb0/messages=From/EmailAddress/Address",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "2aaaaeb...42-ffc6d0e44f3d",
      "date": "2017-01-24T01:30:44"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fetch emails from MS Office API "FROM" specific people without fetching all emails to our system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were missing the character `?` after `messages`. To filter the messages from specify user with unread messages, you can use the request below:

```
GET:https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=from/emailAddress/address+eq+'xx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com'+and+isRead+eq+false
```

Comment: Xue thanks. I don't wanna be pain in the a$$ but here is another one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41839740/office-365-api-erroraccessdenied-access-is-denied-when-sending-an-email.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example of how to do this, and other examples of using common query parameters in Microsoft Graph in [Microsoft Graph optional query parameters](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/query_parameters).