# Office 365 API ErrorAccessDenied Access is denied when sending an email

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

We have an application on Azure that we were already able to read user's email so far after a lot of work and frustration.

For testing purpose I gave the application almost full access (see image)[image] below), including but not limited to sending email on behalf of users, reading users email and etc. I know we don't have to give the application such access unless needed but this is just to make sending email work.

I've this curl code for test purpose to send email

```
 curl -i https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendmail -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"Message":{"Subject": hi", "Body": {"ContentType": "Text", "Content": "body"},"ToRecipients":[{"EmailAddress": {"Address": "alerts-noreply@mail.windowsazure.com"}}]},"SaveToSentItems": "true"}' -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ......TOKEN.....YlhaHbAFQ'
```

and it gave me this error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "4895f98f-c5a4-4083-867b-f6c7b4634b7f",
      "date": "2017-01-24T21:48:47"
    }
  }
}
```

If the Application has such full access, why would the app get denied ?

Token was acquired by the following code:

```
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/f0263....0be3/oauth2/authorize?client_id=8a676..e4b6&redirect_uri=http://www.wrabc.com:8090/&response_type=code.
```

I appericiate your help.

Comment: To narrow down this issue, I suggest that you parse the token form [this site](https://jwt.io/) to check whether there are `Mail.Send` in the `scp` claim.

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT I see the follwoing "scp": "Mail.ReadWrite Mail.ReadWrite.Shared MailboxSettings.ReadWrite User.Read", No Mail.Send.

Comment: I tried POST https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/folders/inbox/messages(to draft messages)  and it worked. I see there is an issue with Mail.Send scope. I went to the permissions in Azure AD and I can see that all are checked including "Send mail as user". After I did that, retrieved a new token and it still doesn't have the mail.send scp. Not sure what I have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute the API of send a message, we need to grant the `Mail.Send` permission. If you change the permission after users have granted the app, the users need to update the permission by re-granting.

Another possible way to re-grant is that add the parameter `prompt=consent` when you init the authorization request. More detail about parameters in the request, you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code).

Comment: Thank you brother. prompt=consent made it work. Not only that, users will be able to see what kind of grant they'll give (which I haven't seen in the past). I wish you guys have documented few examples that does most of the functionality. Things are hard to find. Of course there were mistakes on our end as well, but documentation was a bit tough to guide us thru.

Answer (score 1):

If you added the permission after you gave consent, can you try removing the app for the user at https://myapps.microsoft.com/ or registering a new app? Then sign in and give consent again. That should update the scp for the token.

Comment: There is no remove button. Only report problem and get info.

Comment: Can I manually update the scp ? like in manifest file or something like that ?

Comment: Do you get the Remove option on https://portal.office.com/ ? Click your name in the top right corner, choose "View account", and then "App permissions". I don't know whether you'll get the option here if you don't see it in the other dialog, but I think it's possible.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This is what I see :

You can't revoke permission for these apps
You can't revoke permission because this has been assigned to you as part of a subscription or an admin role.

Comment: Have I made anything wrong when registering the apps ?

Comment: Could you try registering a new app with just the permissions you need? That might help simplify the issue.

Comment: I can try that. I've to change a few more things on different platforms for this to work though.