# Office 365 v2 API Authorization code is malformed or invalid

Tags: azure, office365, office365-restapi, azure-ad-graph-api, adal4j

I've the following auth code copied from the browser for a user who granted our app to use their Office 365 email.

```
code=OAQABAAIAAADRNYRQ3dhRSrm-4K-adpCJ3J3UJ8GyC2qJDvNhlrUAObjph6sQ3A9waeQ5Tr-DA6WzxCdFbvadCRJw2S4a_lwA7MyelZWAPQZOlaB_X_1165CbmTXJMGioU6Cr0DhVTUzIlUv_-Svjp8DBrLVCxcDp5rJMM5mDNR0iGysuDIozWnOaPqCOl35NxPzyktrYK6D1MBptmXOPbhS-stTZXbHJr9gGE3FHzMU0XANXmTm30q4SPaoWPch-S1uFFL4xwS2oUv-lELBdcfIGh5UJBSraabGihVWUnbwBhh8eURSMRwryi7kubUcq0D27S-vIVZhtKopemQ1njAcExO58S7EgAyqbIzMxvmBXBe0X1ieVrcyHYRpt4ZAq1Z4v5HLTrYhx5fGp6AkqhV09yri3bqXaZvw5R1hKuhAbRDt_isZn_L8ZEhfwnqICGUwpDU27c6Qd1txuiOVY90a4BiAUh1M1u5gjDx8nIE88R7S915w7mUjJtCzZuTKQavve8q8UOtm9udUvBOX1f-bYslpgiIRbdSYBYlP9UrbreLS1W6OFk2NX-uqp9mabyImvvj1RUm166qV6uc9hsuhzrfErDURC17JotuQBSWYauAvb38p5B-cDbsCZafpyORlbrWsYyQcdWwUPL0aOZEQXFW-v3gDw7Xri_9hvsiHrj10NTaaozqm1QpZmMf-SHJ0yF9wBWKYgAA
```

Application works without a problem if we are using Microsoft Graph REST API v1 but the following problem happens when using version 2. It is registered with delegate permissions that grants us Read, Write/Send permission which work fine with V1 of the application.

For V2: `authority =https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` and 
to retrive auth code I use the following url

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=30..7&response_type=code&scope=mail.read&redirect_uri=https://myurl:8443/controller/saveToken
```

Code block causing the issue:

```
 @Override
    public AuthenticationResult getToken(String authCode) {

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        OfficeCredentials credentials = getCredentials();

        try {
            AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(credentials.getAuthority(), true, service);
            final Future<AuthenticationResult> resultFuture = context.acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                    authCode, new URI(credentials.getRedirectUri()), new ClientCredential(credentials.getClientId(),
                            credentials.getClientSecret()), credentials.getResourceUrl(), null);

            return resultFuture.get();//throws exception

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());

        }

        return null;

    }
```

Exception when **resultFuture.get()** is called

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: {"error_description":"AADSTS70000: Transmission data parser failure: Authorization Code is malformed or invalid.\r\nTrace ID: c37b4aba-c5fb-44f3-815c-dd798072095d\r\nCorrelation ID: e190ccd2-f98a-440c-8e79-69cfcead3c04\r\nTimestamp: 2017-02-06 17:53:30Z","error":"invalid_grant"}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong as I am trying to migrate to v2. redirect_uri is same as defined in azure and it is HTTPS. I already made my local env't accept HTTPS by following [this](https://dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes). FYI: I am using adal4 java library.

Comment: Did you register a new V2 application for use on the V2 endpoint? To my knowledge, you cannot use the same app on the V1 and V2 endpoint.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi I created a new app for that purpose but where do you tell the app you are working with is v2 or not ?

Comment: You can only register V2 applications using the App Registration Portal as noted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-flows). You will see them under the application section called "Converged Applications" versus "Live SDK Applications", which are MSA specific apps, or "Azure AD only applications" which are V1 apps.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did.

Comment: I repeated the same procedure with a new app. No luck at all. It's just frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, the adal4j library doesn't support the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint(refer [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/adal4j/AuthenticationAuthority.java)). Event we set the authority for the v2.0 endpoint, it still use the old one.

As a workaround, you may compose the HTTP request directly. Here is the sample request for your reference( refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-access-token)):

```
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id={clientId}&client_secret={clientSecret}&scope={scope}&code={authorizationCode}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri={redirectUri}
```

And if you want the adal4j library to support Azure AD v2.0 endpoint, you can submit the feedback from [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java).

Comment: This works great but only brings back access token but no refresh token. Where do I get that info ?

Comment: @WowBow you need the offline_access scope to get a refresh token back.

Comment: Another problem now: I used the following command to get emails for a user who subscribed for v2 "curl -i https://graph.microsoft.com/v2.0/me/messages -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Authorization: Bearer  token..." Now this replies back with invalid version. All the examples on Microsoft site use https://outlook.office.com/v2.0/me/messages so I gave this one a try and I reicieved a message saying we cant display this content. I am a bit lost on what to do on this.

Comment: the url containes https even if SO removed it from the comment.

Comment: More details on the user: User has Azure AD account on office.com so its a company email address.. I used the same email to register the app as well. So this user is not an out look user but same user which exists in the same AD.

Comment: Second issue: for another email which is out of the same AD, I recieved the following auth code "M318eb27d-ef61-dea3-47a2-58e00dd5ab8b" which is somehow shorter than what I used to see... and I couldn't get access token for this person (returns BAD request). I could ask on a new thread but I just get frustrated for asking questions for every single issues as there is no reference I could look in to.

Comment: @Fei Xue, Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: There is only one release version(**v1.0**) and beta version for the Microsoft Graph. For the issue not able to get the access token, is there any detailed error message? In addition, for the new issue, I still suggest to reopen a new thread so that other communities who have same issue can recognize the issue and share their experience quickly.

Comment: @WowBow we offer dozens of code samples for help with Azure AD that may serve as a good reference. Try https://github.com/azure-samples and search for `active-directory-` and you'll get a bunch. Alternatively, to see the entire set of docs, go to aka.ms/aaddev.