# Can't Login with Microsoft Account

Tags: php, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using The "PHP League oauth2-client" to get details of particular user.

But got error :

```
 Array
        (
            [error] => Array
                (
                    [code] => InvalidAuthenticationToken
                    [message] => Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.
                    [innerError] => Array
                        (
                            [request-id] => <reuest-id>
                            [date] => 2019-06-13T07:44:01
                        )

                )

        )
```

I have passed clientId ,clientSecret , redirectUri ,urlAuthorize , urlAccessToken , urlResourceOwnerDetails and got authorizationUrl . When I hit authorizationUrl , it properly redirect with code ,state,session_state . 
I just use this code and got accesstoken array. 
Using accesstoken array ,  I call 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/'api to fetch user details. But got error i.e Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.

Actually , I am trying login with Microsoft

```
$provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
                'clientId'                => '<cid>',    // The client ID assigned to you by the provider
                'clientSecret'            => '<clientSecret>',   // The client password assigned to you by the provider
                'redirectUri'             => 'https://mywebsideurl',
               'urlAuthorize'            => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/authorize',
                'urlAccessToken'          => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token',
                'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<my-microsoft-mail-id>',

            ]);

             $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
                        'code' => '<code>'
                    ]);

            $request = $provider->getAuthenticatedRequest(
                        'GET',
                        'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/',
                        $accessToken
                    );
```

Error :

```
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [code] => InvalidAuthenticationToken
            [message] => Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.
            [innerError] => Array
                (
                    [request-id] => <some id>
                    [date] => 2019-06-12T07:36:49
                )

        )

)
```

I have parse server response :

```
GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response Object
        (
            [reasonPhrase:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Unauthorized
            [statusCode:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => 401
            [headers:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Array
                (
                    [Content-Type] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => application/json; charset=utf-8
                        )

                    [request-id] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => <rid>
                        )

                    [client-request-id] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => <client-request-id>
                        )

                    [x-ms-ags-diagnostic] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"<some place name here>","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"<some number>","ScaleUnit":"<something>","RoleInstance":"something","ADSiteName":"something"}}
                        )

                    [WWW-Authenticate] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Bearer realm="", authorization_uri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize", client_id="<some id here>"
                        )

                    [Strict-Transport-Security] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => max-age=31536000
                        )

                    [Date] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Thu, 13 Jun 2019 07:44:01 GMT
                        )

                    [Content-Length] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => <some length>
                        )

                )

            [headerNames:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Array
                (
                    [content-type] => Content-Type
                    [request-id] => request-id
                    [client-request-id] => client-request-id
                    [x-ms-ags-diagnostic] => x-ms-ags-diagnostic
                    [www-authenticate] => WWW-Authenticate
                    [strict-transport-security] => Strict-Transport-Security
                    [date] => Date
                    [content-length] => Content-Length
                )

            [protocol:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => 1.1
            [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream Object
                (
                    [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Resource id #<some_id>
                    [size:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => <some number>
                    [seekable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
                    [readable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
                    [writable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
                    [uri:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => php://temp
                    [customMetadata:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )
```

> As per my observation server return WWW-Authenticate url is wrong , it
>   should be
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/authorize .
>
> Is there any way to config WWW-Authenticate url from azure  back-end
>   ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration for the provider is not correct. To allow Microsoft account login, you should use [Microsoft identity platform v2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview). When you register your application on Azure portal, remember to **set Supported account types to Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts**.

Here is a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/php-tutorial) for your reference.

```
$oauthClient = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
      'clientId'                => env('OAUTH_APP_ID'),
      'clientSecret'            => env('OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD'),
      'redirectUri'             => env('OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI'),
      'urlAuthorize'            => env('OAUTH_AUTHORITY').env('OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT'),
      'urlAccessToken'          => env('OAUTH_AUTHORITY').env('OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT'),
      'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
      'scopes'                  => env('OAUTH_SCOPES')
    ]);

OAUTH_APP_ID=YOUR_APP_ID_HERE
OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD=YOUR_APP_PASSWORD_HERE
OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:8000/authorize
OAUTH_SCOPES='openid profile offline_access User.Read Mail.Read'
OAUTH_AUTHORITY=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common
OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT=/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT=/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Comment: I am trying it , but got cURL error 3: malformed , when put urlResourceOwnerDetails => ' '

Comment: @Arif Did you follow the document? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/php-tutorial

Comment: Yes.. 

When I put urlResourceOwnerDetails empty i got cURL error 3: malformed.

But When I put urlResourceOwnerDetails = https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<my_microsoft_account_id>' and put 'scopes'                   => 'openid profile offline_access User.Read Mail.Read',..

Comment: Now got another error : `Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [code] => InvalidAuthenticationToken
            [message] => CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217
            [innerError] => Array
                (
                    [request-id] => <some_id>
                    [date] => 2019-06-14T07:03:06
                )

        )

)`

This error coming when I am trying :

` $request = $provider->getAuthenticatedRequest(
            'GET',
            'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/',
            $accessToken
        );`

Comment: @Arif what is the detailed error message? You can get the token, right?

Comment: I made small mistake there.. i.e 

I should put there :

  `  'urlAuthorize'            => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tid>/v2.0/authorize',
    'urlAccessToken'          => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tid>/oauth2/v2.0/token' `

As I am using  oauth2-client ..
Now I got data....no error now.. thanks you for helping me

Comment: Yes from this answer .. I got important url of azure documentation ..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754060/invalidauthenticationtoken-compacttoken-parsing-failed-with-error-code-21471 --> this link also help me to clear urlAuthorize , urlAccessToken

Comment: Could you please help me .  I pass                 'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<my-microsoft-mail-id>', So I need to pass here user <my-microsoft-mail-id> . With out passing any <my-microsoft-mail-id> , I want login with azure .. Like login with facebook